# How do I split/parse a URL string into an object?

Tags: string, powershell, object, url

I'm trying to split a URL into an object.

```
$url = "https://api.somedomain.com/v2/direct-access/producing-entities-details?entity_id=104194825&format=json&page=1
```

The desired result would be

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $url.api 
https://api.somedomain.com/v2/direct-access

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $url.dataset
producing-entities-details

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $url.params
entity_id=104194825&format=json&page=1
```

I'm sure this can be done in combination with regex, but I am also wondering if this can be done just using built in PowerShell functionality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to mess around with regex. The [`[uri]` type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.7.2) would do some of that work for you. The other parts seem specific to how you choose to interpret the data and not how URL anatomy works.

```
PS C:\Users\matt> $url = [uri]"https://api.somedomain.com/v2/direct-access/producing-entities-details?entity_id=104194825&format=json&page=1"

PS C:\Users\matt> $url.Query
?entity_id=104194825&format=json&page=1
```

You can explore the other properties and see how they will help you. For instance, you might need to build the Segments to get the other parts you are looking for.

```
PS C:\Users\matt>   $url.Segments
/
v2/
direct-access/
producing-entities-details
```

Answer (score 6):

```bsh
$url = "https://api.somedomain.com/v2/direct-access/producing-entities-details?entity_id=104194825&format=json&page=1"

$uri = [System.Uri]$url

$ParsedQueryString = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($uri.Query)

$i = 0
$queryParams = @()
foreach($QueryStringObject in $ParsedQueryString){
    $queryObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $queryObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Query -Value $QueryStringObject
    $queryObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Value -Value $ParsedQueryString[$i]
    $queryParams += $queryObject
    $i++
}
$queryParams
```

Output:

```bsh
Query     Value
-----     -----
entity_id 104194825
format    json
page      1
```